# 100+ warnings in new Xcode 7.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-warnings

I have updated the latest version of Xcode 7.1. I am getting around 100+ compiler warnings.

**Example:**

```
warning: /Users/2141/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/2GQZ88U0K6E0E/ObjectiveC-2CD0WTQVXITO7.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
while processing /Users/mohideen-2141/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NoteBook-bldlsbruffeylydfevskmbnsmjfm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libAFNetworking.a(AFURLRequestSerialization.o):
```

Comment: Try cleaning your build folder.  opt+shift+cmd+K.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To delete the derived data, Alt-Click on "Go" in the Finder top bar. Then select "Library", navigate to Developer/Xcode/DerivedData and delete the entire folder.

Answer (score 2):

Delete your derived data, for starters

Answer (score 2):

On command line:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```